# ImportError: cannot import name 'Timedelta' from 'pandas._libs.tslibs'

Tags: python-3.x

## I am trying to import pandas in spyder with python 3.7

I tried reinstalling pandas using conda install -f pandas 
creating different environment

> import pandas as pd

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<ipython-input-7-7dd3504c366f>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd

  File "C:\Users\mrpaw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *

  File "C:\Users\mrpaw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper

  File "C:\Users\mrpaw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (

  File "C:\Users\mrpaw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

  File "C:\Users\mrpaw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 66, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs

  File "C:\Users\mrpaw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pandas.core.internals import BlockManager

  File "C:\Users\mrpaw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .blocks import (  # noqa:F401

  File "C:\Users\mrpaw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.tslibs import Timedelta, conversion, is_null_datetimelike

ImportError: cannot import name 'Timedelta' from 'pandas._libs.tslibs' 
(C:\Users\mrpaw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\__init__.py)
```

## ImportError: cannot import name 'Timedelta' from 'pandas._libs.tslibs' (C:\Users\mrpaw\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\tslibs__init__.py)